# Socket select() blocks other UI threads

Tags: c++, mfc

In my MFC application , I am using TCP/IP socket for communcating and getting data from a server.During this process I am displaying a modelless dialog with static text and progress control.During communication I am updating the static text and progress control in a separate user thread(AfxBeginThread).

If I try to communicate to wrong ip the sockets select function with timeout value 5 secs  blocking the displaying of dialog with static text and progress control(I.e the dialog hangs, the controls are getting displayed).

Once the socket comes out from select function the dialog is getting displayed properly.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In MFC, I'd *strongly* recommend using `CAsyncSocket`s, and just reacting when data comes in from the server. You probably have no need to spin up a thread at all.

If you were going to spin up a separate thread for part of the job, you'd want to allocate tasks to threads somewhat differently. You always want to leave UI updates in the main thread (the one that was created by default). If you were going to use (for example) a blocking socket, and call select on it, you'd want to move *that* work to a separate thread, and leave the UI updates in the thread that was created by default. Then the thread handling the socket could (for example) send messages to the UI thread to tell it about what's going on, so it could update the UI appropriately. But, as already noted, you probably just want to use a `CAsyncSocket`, in which case you won't need a second thread at all.